# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when using CherryPy 3.2 Basic Authentication

Tags: python, cherrypy

My site configures CherryPy by way of a configuration file.  In the configuration file I am trying to setup basic authentication.  I have specified the fully qualified path to a "checkpassword" function.  But I'm getting an error about the tools.auth_basic.checkpassword line.

[Most of the samples online](http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/refman/lib/auth_basic.html), do not use a config file. So it's making things more difficult.

My config file:

```
[/]
tools.auth_basic.on = True
tools.auth_basic.realm = "some site"
tools.auth_basic.checkpassword = "Infrastructure.App.Authentication.FindPassword"
```

My startweb.py file:

```
import ...
...

cherrypy.tree.mount(DesktopRootController(), "/", "auth.conf")

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

The error message:

```
[10/Sep/2011:12:51:29] HTTP Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "lib.zip\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 642, in respond
   self.hooks.run('before_handler')
 File "lib.zip\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 97, in run
   hook()
 File "lib.zip\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 57, in __call__
   return self.callback(**self.kwargs)
 File "lib.zip\cherrypy\lib\auth_basic.py", line 76, in basic_auth
   if checkpassword(realm, username, password):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

My "callable" is defined here:

```
import cherrypy

class Authentication:
    def FindPassword(realm, username, password):
        print realm
        print username
        print password
        return "password"
```

And this is some of the "App" class:

```
from Authentication import Authentication

class App:
    def __call__(self):
        return self

    def __init__(self):
        self._authentication = Authentication

    @property
    def Authentication(self):
        return _authentication
```

Comment: If I change the config line to this: tools.auth_basic.checkpassword =  Infrastructure.App.Authentication.FindPassword then it works a little bit better.  But I get a new error:  TypeError: unbound method FindPassword() must be called with Authentication inst
ance as first argument (got str instance instead)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution!

First, fix the config file like this.  Remove the quotes from the function name:

```
tools.auth_basic.checkpassword =  Infrastructure.App.Authentication.FindPassword
```

Second, add the @staticmethod keyword to the checkpassword function:

```
@staticmethod
def FindPassword(realm, username, password):
    print realm
    print username
    print password
    return "password"
```

Comment: Yes, remove the quotes. But rather than use `staticmethod`, if you have a single function that doesn't need to access instance state, just take it out of the class and make it a module-level function. You can use classes to gather related functions together, but that's done more rarely in Python than other langs--other Python devs will find heavy use of staticmethod jarring.

Comment: I'm learned that Python devs do a lot of things different that devs in other languages.  I'm not sure how I feel about that yet.  BTW, I love cherrypy.  Nice work Fumanchu!

Answer (score 0):

CherryPy config options are always regular python values.  If you want to describe a module variable, you have to find a way to import it into the config file.

```
[/]
tools.auth_basic.on = True
tools.auth_basic.realm = "some site"
tools.auth_basic.checkpassword = __import__("Infrastructure.App.Authentication").App.Authentication.FindPassword
```

Edit: It looks like cherrypy's option parser chokes on the import keyword; you'll have to use the even longer, even less DRY form like this.

Edit2: the next problem you have is a missing `self` parameter.  Change your authentication class to this:

```
class Authentication:
    def FindPassword(self, realm, username, password):
        #            ^^^^^
        print realm
        print username
        print password
        return "password"
```

Comment: what happened to the other guy's answer?

Comment: I'm getting this error now: ValueError: ('Config error in section: \'/\', option: \'tools.auth_basic.checkpassword\', value: \'__import__("Infrastructure.App.Authentication", fromlist="FindPassword").FindPassword\'. Config values must be valid Python.', 'TypeError', (
"unrepr does not recognize 'Keyword'",))

Comment: tools.auth_basic.checkpassword =  Infrastructure.App.Authentication.FindPassword This works a little better, but I get a different error: 

TypeError: unbound method FindPassword() must be called with Authentication inst
ance as first argument (got str instance instead)