# Cherrypy Basic Authentication Config File TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python, authentication, configuration, app-config, cherrypy

I'm trying to do basic authentication in cherrypy using config put in a separate file. Following the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373572/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-when-using-cherrypy-3-2-basic-authentica) my code is as below. I would get the pop-up window asking for my credentials, but after entering, the server would crash with the error message: "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

**app.py**

```
class MyApp(object):
 ...
def checkUser(realm,user,pwd):
 if user == 'validUser' and pwd == 'validPwd':
  return True
 return False
if __name__ == '__main__':
 cherrypy.tree.mount(MyApp(),"/secure","secure.conf")
 cherrypy.engine.start()
 cherrypy.engine.block()
```

**secure.conf**

```
[/]
tools.auth_basic.on = True,
tools.auth_basic.realm = "here",
tools.auth_basic.accept_charset : 'UTF-8',
tools.auth_basic.checkpassword : app.checkUser
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the comma at the end each entry in **secure.conf**

It should look like this

```
[/]
tools.auth_basic.on = True
tools.auth_basic.realm = "here"
```